# Keyword Replacement in Template Document (API)

Tags: docusignapi

I want to replace some keywords in template document with some text and as per the solution found by the API is that the text gets imposed over the keyword and the keyword is also visible.

I just want to know that is there any way through API, to replace keywords fully from the document with the text we want and hides the keyword.

Answer (score 1):

Re "*as per the solution found by the API is that the text gets imposed over the keyword and the keyword is also visible*" -- this describes how **anchor text** works in DocuSign. DocuSign will never actually modify the contents of the underlying (original) document; it will simply overlay tabs (text, input fields, etc.) on top of your original document in the places that you specify.

To achieve your goal, I'd suggest that you "hide" the keywords in your document by setting the *text color* of each keyword to match the *background color* of your document. For example, if the *background color* of the document is **white**, set the *text color* of each keyword to **white**. This will make it so that the keyword text is invisible in the document (but still detectable by Docusign) -- when DocuSign overlays text in those locations, only that text will be visible.